# I can't build a library that needs WOW64 Api

Tags: c++, winapi, wow64

I'm fixing a bug with Windows Vista 64 bits of a 32bit application, when I try to use the function Wow64DisableWow64FsRedirection(...) the compiler says 'undeclared identifier...'.

I'm including the Windows.h header file and set _WIN32_WINNT to 0x0501.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

EDIT: We're using MS Visual Studio 2003

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you see this API in the header file? May be the Visual Studio you are using is not having updated header file, in which case you will need to do a LoadLibrary for Kernel32.dll and then GetProcAddress for the required function.

Answer (score 3):

Your platform SDK files are probably too old to have that function. That function first appeared in the XP 64 bit platform SDK. You can get the latest SDK here: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=e6e1c3df-a74f-4207-8586-711ebe331cdc&displaylang=en

Even though it says it's "The Windows SDK for Windows Server® 2008" it is just the latest SDK and will have all the backwards compatible files you need.

After you install it, depending on your compiler you'll probably have to point the include directory to it.

Answer (score 1):

If your application needs to work on Windows XP 32-bit or Windows 2000, you should use `LoadLibrary()` and `GetProcAddress()` as Canopus suggested, because `Wow64DisableWow64FsRedirection()` and `Wow64RevertWow64FsRedirection()` were not added until Windows XP 64-bit and Server 2003 SP1 (according to the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365743.aspx)).